# htaccess on wordpress redirects loop

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

This question might have been asked before but I believe this case is different, if not please allow me to know and I remove the post.

So I have a WP site  V3.9.1 & I realised after upgrading to this version google bots and sitemap couldnt be fetched. So I checked webmaster tools and I can see my domain shows as www.mydomain.com and each time google bots try to fetch it redirects them to domain without www

I added redirect to my .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now when I add this I still get redirect loop

Domains on my WP settings are as below:

siteurl: http://domain.com
home: http://domain.com

I really don't know how to resolve this, any ideas would be perfect.

Thank you all

Comment: Make sure above rule is your very first rule in WP .htaccess file and test in a new browser.

Comment: Thanks, Ive done that and added www to site url and home field but still getting redirect loop issue

Comment: Why did you add `www` to site url and home field? I think your rule is removing `www` so site url and home field should also be without www

Comment: No I actually, I'd like to add www to URL - currently url is domain.com and need it to be www.domain.com

Comment: I have them without www now and htaccess causes error loop in website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your rule like this as your **very first rewrite rule** in WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Then keep

```
site url: http://www.domain.com
home url: http://www.domain.com
```

Comment: Thanks, done this and I thought this is the way but it keep looping

Comment: There is something that strips `www`. I opened `www.domain.com` using command like curl and I got 301 redirect to `http://domain.com/`. Most likely you have some plugin or rule somewhere doing this.